# Bot meant to react to certain User: Where is my mistake?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

I want my bot to react to a certain msg by a certain user, but it won't work.This is what I used:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(msg): 
    if msg.author == client.user: 
        return
    text = msg.content.lower() 
    print(text) 
    if message.author.id == 123456 and "hi" in text: 
        await msg.channel.send("hi")
```

Tried this and get no answer

```
@client.event
async def on_message(msg): 
    if msg.author == client.user: 
        return
    text = msg.content.lower() 
    print(text) 
    if "hi" in text: 
        await msg.channel.send("hi")
```

If I delete the user id part it works fine, so the rest should be ok

Comment: @EliHarold

Tried it like this:
`if msg.author.id == '123456' and "hi" in text: 
        await msg.channel.send("hi")`

Did not work :/ Rest seems fine and works, but not this.

Comment: Do you get an error message or just nothing?

Comment: `print(message.author.id)` and see what it gives you.

Comment: @EliHarold thank you!!! it worked (somehow) finally. No idea what changed :D

Comment: I looked it up and user.id gives you an int, so it should be `== 123456` not `== '123456'` (your code was correct in this sense).